# Spree for wholesale/retail system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need to build an e-commerce where if user buys a single product, the price is X, but if he buys more than 100 products for example, the price will be Y. It´s a wholesale/retail e-commerce. I wanna know if Spree can do this for me.
Anyone built something like that with Spree?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of Spree extensions for that:

- [Volume Pricing](http://spreecommerce.com/extensions/2-volume-pricing)
- [Simple Volume Pricing](http://spreecommerce.com/extensions/129-simple-volume-pricing)